# edit or Udate a post using React Hooks reducer and Context

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

Please Can someone help me out here. I am creating an Application using react hooks Context and hooks reducers which has a post form with multiple input fields. Can someone help me out on how to edit the posts using react hooks useReducers and useContext. Ithnk the prolem is coming from the useEffect function in my Planfrom.Js. after clicking the edit button the in the PlanForm.js file the clicked post is suppose to appear at the form input field but not happens. Thanks for you help this has been giving me problems.

below are my codes...

**PlanList contains the list of planed activities**

```
    enter code hereimport React, {useContext} from 'react'
import ItemsContext from '../context'
import './PlanList.css'

function PlanList() {
    const {state, dispatch} = useContext(ItemsContext)
    const title = state.items.length > 0 ? `You have ${state.items.length} fitness goals` : "You have any current fitness plans"


    return(
        <div>
            <h3 className="mb-2">{title}</h3>
            <ul>
                {state.items.map(item => (
                    <li key={item.id} 
                    className="px-2 flex flex-col mb-4" >
                        <span>{item.day}</span>
                        <span>{item.toTrain}</span>
                        <span>{item.muscleGroup}</span> 
                        <span>{item.isFood}</span>
                        <div>
                            <input className="cursor-pointer" type="checkbox"
                             onClick = {()=> dispatch({type:"TOGGLE_COMPLETE", payload:item})}/>
                        </div>
                        <div className="flex flex-row space-x-4">
                        <button type="button" onClick={() => dispatch({type:"SET_CURRENT_ITEM", payload:item})}>Edit</button>
                        <button type="button" onClick={() => dispatch({type:"REMOVE_ITEM", payload:item})}>Delete</button>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                ))}
            </ul>
        </div>
    )
}

export default PlanList

**the Context...**

    import React from 'react'

const ItemsContext = React.createContext({
    items:[
       {
        id:1,
        day: 'Monday',
        toTrain:'Bicep curls, Lat pull down',
        muscleGroup:'Biceps',
        isFood:'Potatoes',
        isCompleted: false
    },
    {
        id:2,
        day: 'Tuesday',
        toTrain:'Bench press',
        muscleGroup:'Chest',
        isFood:'Beef lavaganza',
        isCompleted:false
    },
    {
        id:3,
        day: 'Wednesday' , 
        toTrain:'Triceps extensions',
        muscleGroup:'Triceps',
        isFood:'Chicken soup',
        isCompleted:false
    }
    ],
    currentItem: {}
})

export default ItemsContext



**Reducers...**

    import { v4 as uuidv4 } from 'uuid'

function reducer(state, action){
    switch(action.type){
        case "ADD_ITEM":
            const  newItem = {
                id:uuidv4(),
                day:action.payload.day,
                toTrain:action.payload.toTrain,
                muscleGroup:action.payload.muscleGroup,
                isFood:action.payload.isFood,
                isCompleted:false
            }

            const addedItems = [...state.items, newItem]

            return{
                ...state,
                items:addedItems
            }

        case "SET_CURRENT_ITEM":
            return{
                ...state,
                currentItem: action.payload
            }   

        case "TOGGLE_COMPLETE":
        const toggledItems = state.items.map(i =>
             i.id === action.payload.id ? {...action.payload, isCompleted:!action.payload.isCompleted}:i
             )
             return {
                 ...state,
                 items:toggledItems
             }
        case "REMOVE_ITEM":
            const filteredItems = state.items.filter(i => i.id !== action.payload.id)
            return {
                ...state,
                items:filteredItems
            }
            default:
                return state
    }
}

export default reducer



**Planform, contains the form where you fill the planed activities...**

import React, {useState, useEffect, useContext} from 'react'
import ItemsContext from '../context'

function PlanForm() {
    let InitialState =
    {
        day:'',
        toTrain:'',
        muscleGroup:'',
        isFood:''
    }

    const {state:{currentItem = {}}, dispatch} = useContext(ItemsContext)
    const [values, setValues] = useState(InitialState)

      useEffect(() => {
        if(currentItem.InitialState){
            setValues(currentItem.InitialState)
        }
    }, [currentItem.id])  **//where I think the problem is coming from**


    function handleChange(e){
        e.persist()
        setValues(previousValues => ({
            ...previousValues,
            [e.target.name]:e.target.value
        }))
    }

    function handleSubmit(e){
        e.preventDefault()
        dispatch({type:'ADD_ITEM', payload:values})
        setValues(InitialState)
    }

    return (
        <div>
          <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
            <div>
              <div>
                  <label>
                      Day
                     <input type="text" name = "day" value={values.day} onChange={handleChange}/> 
                  </label>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div>
                <div>
                    <label>Training Exercise</label>
                    <textarea className="resize border rounded 
                    focus:outline-none focus:shadow-outline" name="toTrain" value={values.toTrain} onChange={handleChange}></textarea>
                    <p>Describe what training exercises would you like to do today?</p>
                    <div>
                        <label>Muscle group</label>
                        <input type="text" name = "muscleGroup" value={values.muscleGroup} onChange={handleChange}/>
                        <p>what muscle group would you like to train today?</p>
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <label>Nourishment</label>
                        <input type="text" name = "isFood" value={values.isFood} onChange={handleChange}/>
                        <p>what would you like to eat today?</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <button className= "bg-red-600 rounded py-2 px-4" type="submit">Submit</button>
          </form>
        </div>
    )
}

export default PlanForm
```